# Redundancy : I used to visit her and I(?) always wondered why she had those dreadful pictures on the wall

Tags: redundancy

> I used to visit her and I always wondered why she had those dreadful pictures on the wall.

If I remove the second *I* from the sentence, will it be grammatically correct ? I.e.

> I used to visit her and always wondered why she had those dreadful pictures on the wall.

Is this grammatically correct and good for formal usage ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this answer: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145218/grammar-check-on-a-sentence-with-one-subject-many-verbs-in-sequence-and-no-con

You are essentially doing the same, this is, setting the subject once (*I*), and using multiple verbs for the different actions that the subject performs (visit her and wonder).